# Label word wrap in Textblock not working

Tags: wpf, word-wrap

I have a WPF page with quite a few objects. At the bottom of all these items, I have a label that needs to have textwrapping in the content. That answer is simple, with the use of a Textblock this should be a cinch. However, even though I use those items, I still can't get th e text to wrap. So I'm assuming that there must be other settings in the other objects that I need to check/modify. In pseudo code, my XAML looks like

```
<Page>
  <Stackpanel vertical>
   <Border>
    <Stackpanel vertical>
     <label></label>
    <Stackpanel horizontal>
     <label></label>
    </stackpanel>
   <label>
    <textblock TextWrapping="Wrap">
   </label>
  </border>
 </stackpanel>
</page>
```

What am I missing here? Should I be checking other elements? I have already made sure that none of the nesting elements have any height specified - they are all set to auto.

Comment: Is your textblock auto resizing?  If it is, the wrapping might not take effect.

Comment: Not sure I understand that. Wouldnt you need auto resize since it could be 1 or 2 or X lines? If it shouldnt be auto, then what should it be?

Comment: auto resize will extend the width of the textblock as far as it can go to fit the text BEFORE wrapping.  Try giving it a maxwidth property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and post this as an answer in case someone else gets stuck on this.

When you set the `Width` and `Height` properties of the `TextBlock` control, it will first horizontally increase in size to accommodate as much text as it can *before* wrapping the text (if the `TextWrapping` property is set to Wrap).  Once it decides it needs to wrap the text, if the `Height` is set to Auto, the text box will resize vertically to accommodate the text (until it hits the bottom of whatever UI container you put it in).  If you do not want the text box to resize past a certain point, you will need to set values for the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` properties.  This will force the `TextBlock` to wrap at a certain width.

Answer (score 1):

With my XamlPadX, this wraps:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Width="300">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
     <Label>L1</Label>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Label>L2</Label>
     </StackPanel>
     <Label>
       <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
         This text wraps.
         This text wraps.
         This text wraps.
         This text wraps.
         This text wraps.
         This text wraps.
         This text wraps.
       </TextBlock>
     </Label>
   </StackPanel>
 </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

So the problem must be somewhere else.